# c struct with zero sized array members

Tags: c, arrays, android-source

I encountered some syntax in an Android open source code that I can't understand. There is a struct that looks something like this:

```
struct __attribute__((packed)) A
{
    uint8_t bla;
    uint8_t bla2;
    uint8_t someFixedSizeArr[20];
    uint8_t padded[0]; // Marks offset to padded data
    uint8_t someFixedSizeArr2[30];
    uint8_t transformed[0]; // Marks offset to transformed data
    int32_t length;
    uint8_t result[100];
};
```

I don't understand what padded and transformed are and how they work. Later on, a type B's ctor (which wraps A) doesn't touch them, so they are un-initialized when B is created, yet later on they are referenced as such:

```
memmove(&A.padded[padLength], &A.result[A.length], 30);
```

And also:

```
someFunc(A.transformed, 30, A.someFixedSizeArr);
```

So what happens here, memory wise, with these zero sized arrays? Note that I read about zero sized arrays but this doesn't seem to match what I read, because there it stated that the array must be the last field of a struct, which is not the case here.

Comment: C or C++?  C++ does not support zero sized arrays

Comment: Standard C++ doesn't support that, it's a language extension. A common language extension is to support zero-sized array at *the end of* a `struct`. That's used as a dynamic length array (by allocating more than the direct `struct` size).

Comment: `A` doesn't have a constructor.

Comment: Bottom line: we'll need to know the exact compiler being used for anybody to hope to help, since this is only even allowed because that compiler provides an extension to support it.

Comment: An explanation of how zero length arrays work can be found in gcc's documentation: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

Comment: looks like the compiler handle this, as i see it's just pointer to nothing...

Comment: @SergeyA, thanks for pointing that out. I had confused the terms `flexible array member` with `variable length array`. Still early in the day for me. While a zero-length array is not technically a flexible array member, they serve the same purpose. The difference being flexible array members are standardized in C99, you may only have one in a struct, and it must be the last member.

Comment: @felisimo, there is no answer to that. This code is not correct as to C spec, and this code is not correct as to gcc extension spec (`Flexible array members may only appear as the last member of a struct that is otherwise non-empty.`). You might want to ask the same question to whoever authored (or supports) this code.

Comment: @felisimo it is just as expressed. `uint8_t transformed[0]` is basically a pointer to an array with zero elements and behaves like any other result of `a[n]` including that you cannot access more than `[n]` elements of the array. Well what does that get you, why not just a pointer to a dynamically sized array? Zero-length arrays are only useful when you have a large struct that requires a dynamic length field and you need to share the structure *across systems*.

Comment: Note the `length` field just below `transformed` this is most likely the array length of `transformed`. Effectively, the struct is variable sized. For the receiver to calculate the size of the struct, it would read `length` and calculate the size of `transformed` to determine the size of the struct. Since the receiver is a different system than the sender, options are limited. You would not able to alloc pointers inside the struct as they wouldn't point to memory on the receiver's system.

Comment: `padded` appears to just offset the data in the structure for alignment, but it would be hard to determine exactly what it's doing without seeing the relevant source.

Comment: These zero sized array will always have zero elements because they are not at the end of the struct. And they won't change the layout of A because of the packed attribute. The only information they provide is two offsets, that divides the structure in three part. The aim may be to provide a stable interface for code using `offsetof`: `memcpy((unsigned char*)(&a_A)+offsetof(A,transformed),a_transformed,sizeof(A)-offsetof(A,transformed))`

Answer (score 2):

> These are few things you should know first about zero-sized arrays in a struct :

- A zero sized array declaration was a constraint violation (this requiring a diagnostic) in ISO C 90 in all contexts: even as a function parameter, where the identifier being declared is actually a pointer and not an array at all!
- C99 added the "flexible array member" feature: the last element of a struct can be an array of size zero: "As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a flexible array member.
- In C90 code, the "struct hack" is implemented using an array of size [1] at the end of a struct. Some compilers allowed zero (like GNU C, I think) before C99.

we must use offsetof(type, last_member) so that we exclude [1] from the calculation:

```
struct foo {
/* ... */
int array[ZERO_OR_ONE];
};

/* Correct in C99, if ZERO_OR_ONE is 0
 Incorrect in C90, (ZERO_OR_ONE can't be zero).  */
size_t foo_plus_3_elems = sizeof (struct foo) + 3 * sizeof(int);

/* Correct in C99 whether or not ZERO_OR_ONE is 0 or 1.
 Correct in C90 with ZERO_OR_ONE being 1. */
size_t foo_plus_3_elems = offsetof (struct foo, array) + 3 * sizeof(int);
```

- Here, "incorrect" means we calculate slightly more storage than needed, usually without any downside.
- "Correct in C90" means de facto correct, not that it was well-defined behavior. "Everyone" was doing it.

Comment: I am not sure if this comment is relevant to the struct I presented. The zero-sized-arrays in the struct are not in the end.

Comment: There's a difference between "size zero array" and "incomplete array type".  Strictly speaking, the flexible array member should be declared with `[]` and NOT with `[0]` or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

It is just as expressed.

`uint8_t transformed[0]` is for practical purposes a "pointer" to an array with zero elements and behaves like any other result of `a[n]` including that you cannot access more than `[n]` elements of the array.

Well what does that get you, why not just a pointer to a dynamically sized array? Zero-length arrays are only useful when you have a large struct that requires a dynamic length field and you need to share the structure across programs, systems, program runs, etc. In these cases, you cannot allocate a pointer inside the struct as they wouldn't point to memory on the receiver's system. Effectively, the struct is variable sized.

Note the field named `length` just below `transformed`; This is most likely the array length of `transformed`. For the receiver to calculate the size of the struct, it would read length and calculate the size of transformed to determine the size of the struct. (`length*sizeof(uint8_t)`)

You can think of zero-length arrays as a pointer whose contents are inlined at itself and very much like a flexible array member, however it lacks the safety (if you could call it safety) of flexible array members.

You have not provided enough code to delve into what `uint8_t padding[0]` might be doing, but that combined with `__attribute__((packed))` would lead me to believe they found it necessary to manually manage the struct's memory layout, but again, the relevant code is missing to deduce that.