# Why is one of my struct members undefined after attempting to change it in a function? I passed the struct as reference

Tags: arrays, c, function, struct, undefined-behavior

I am writing code for a search_tree() function which fills a chArray struct (dynamic char array) with all the files in a directory and its sub-directories.

However, I'm having problems with the add_elements() function, which is meant to add elements to the char array and adjust its size accordingly.

The array.size member is undefined after the function call, even though I passed the chArray variable as reference to the function.

Why is this happening?

-Apart from this I'm having memory allocation errors, but I'm nearly sure the reason for this is this issue with array.size being undefined.

Thank you for any help!!

P.S. I've included my entire code below, sorry for all the random print statements and weird names - this was me trying to figure out what was wrong.

```
//
// Created by mario on 05/03/2022.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#ifndef errno
extern int errno;
#endif

typedef struct {
    int init;
    int numEls;
    size_t size;
    char **elements;
} chArray;

void initArray(chArray *arr, int n, ...) {
    size_t c_size = 0;
    va_list ptr;
    arr = malloc(sizeof(chArray));
    *arr = (chArray) {.init = 1, .numEls = n, .size = sizeof(chArray), .elements = NULL};
    va_start(ptr, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char *arg = va_arg(ptr, char*);
        c_size += strlen(arg) + 1;
        printf("%lu\n", c_size);
        if (i == 0) {
            arr->elements = (char **) malloc(strlen(arg) + 1);
        }
        else {
            arr->elements = realloc(arr->elements, arr->size + strlen(arg) + 1);
        }
        *(arr->elements + i) = arg;
    }
    va_end(ptr);
    arr->size = c_size + offsetof(chArray, elements);
    printf("%lu\n", arr->size);
}

void add_elements(chArray *arr, int n, ...) {
    va_list ptr;
    size_t new_size = arr->size;
    va_start(ptr, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char *f_arg = va_arg(ptr, char *);
        new_size += strlen(f_arg) + 1;
    }
    va_end(ptr);
    arr = realloc(arr, new_size);
    va_start(ptr, n);
    for (int i = arr->numEls; i < n+arr->numEls; i++) {
        char *arg = va_arg(ptr, char*);
        arr->size += strlen(arg) + 1;
        if (i == 0) {
            arr->elements = (char **) malloc(strlen(arg) + 1);
        }
        else {
            arr->elements = realloc(arr->elements, arr->size + strlen(arg) + 1);
        }
        *(arr->elements + i) = arg;
    }
    va_end(ptr);
    arr->numEls += n;
}

int search_tree(char *tree, char *contains, chArray *ends) {
    struct dirent *entry;
    DIR *dir;
    struct stat buff;
    mode_t mode;

    char *not1 = ".";
    char *not2 = "..";

    unsigned long int tree_length = strlen(tree);
    char *last = tree + tree_length - 1;
#ifdef _WIN32
    if (last != '\\') {
        char *slash = "\\\0";
#else
    if (*last != '/') {
        char *slash = "/\0";
#endif
        if (*last == '\\') {
            char *temp = (char *) malloc(tree_length + 1);
            memset(temp, '\0', tree_length + 1);
            strncpy(temp, tree, tree_length - 1);
            tree = 0;
            tree = (char *) malloc(tree_length + 2);
            strcpy(tree, temp);
            strcat(tree, slash);
            free(temp);
        }
        else {
            char *temp = (char *) malloc(tree_length + 2);
            memset(temp, '\0', tree_length + 2);
            strcpy(temp, tree);
            tree = 0;
            tree = (char *) malloc(tree_length + 2);
            strcpy(tree, temp);
            strcat(tree, slash);
            free(temp);
        }
    }

    if (ends->init != 1) {
        printf("Once\n");
        initArray(ends, 0);
    }

    if ((dir = opendir(tree)) == NULL) {
        perror("An error occurred");
        fprintf(stderr, "Errno = %d", errno);
        return -1;
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        size_t length = strlen(tree) + strlen(entry->d_name) + 1;
        char *file_path = (char *) malloc(length);
        memset(file_path, '\0', length);
        strcpy(file_path, tree);
        strcat(file_path, entry->d_name);
        if (stat(file_path, &buff) != -1) {
            mode = buff.st_mode;
            if (S_ISDIR(mode) && (strcmp(entry->d_name, not1) != 0) && (strcmp(entry->d_name, not2) != 0)) {
                search_tree(file_path, contains, ends);
                for (int i = 0; i < ends->numEls; i++) {
                    printf("%s\n", *(ends->elements));
                }
            } else if (S_ISREG(mode)) {
                if (contains == NULL) {
                    add_elements(ends, 1, file_path);
                    for (int i = 0; i < ends->numEls; i++) {
                        printf("%s\n", *(ends->elements));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (strstr(file_path, contains) != NULL) {
                        add_elements(ends, 1, file_path);
                        for (int i = 0; i < ends->numEls; i++) {
                            printf("%s\n", *(ends->elements));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            perror("An error occurred");
            fprintf(stderr, "Errno = %d", errno);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char *path = "/Users/mario/python";
    char *toComp = "python";

    // printf("%d\n", strcmp(strstr(path, "python"), toComp));

    chArray test;

    initArray(&test, 3, "Hello", "There", "Goodbye");
    printf("%lu\n", test.size);

    add_elements(&test, 10, "Soyez", "Jiduan", "Chifa3n", "Chifa4n", "Chifa5n", "Chif6an", "Chifan7", "Chifa8n", "Chifan9", "Chifan10");

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", *(test.elements + i));
    }
    chArray ends;
    char *tree = "/Users/mario/Desktop";
    search_tree(tree, ".py", &ends);
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(ends));
    printf("%s\n%s\n", *ends.elements, *(ends.elements + 1));

    chArray *random = (chArray * ) malloc(48);
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(*random));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

36

4486016032

search_tree(4025,0x117c5a600) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ff7b48d0838: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
search_tree(4025,0x117c5a600) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

The 36 is the array's size printed from within the add_elements() function, and the second number is the same but printed just after the function.

What is going on?

Comment: Are you compiling this for WIN32?  `if (last != '\\') {` is probably not what you really want.

Comment: line 40  `*(arr->elements + i) = arg;`.  I think that is trying to copy a string. But thats not how you do that, use `strcpy`

Comment: You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works. In particular, I'd encourage you to read [ask] and [mre]. There is far too much excess code in your post, and you've failed to include the exact error message you're receiving.

Comment: I also suspect that you are trying to grow chArray, ie have that last field be variable size. But thats not what you are doing, you are simply dynamically creating and resizing memory that elements points to.

Comment: @KenWhite thank you for the suggestion! This is literally my first post on StackOverflow, so I have yet to familiarise myself with the customs. I will read up on this links you sent!

Comment: @pm100 thank you! I was going to use strcpy() but I wasn't sure that was the correct way to go about it in an array of char arrays, but I'll give it a go!

Comment: @pm100 ah and regarding your second comment, would you be able to point me in the right direction regarding the correct way of creating a dynamic char array? Thank you

Comment: dynamic char array question. You are mixing two things together and you need to decide which one you want. One is actually groing a field at the end of a struct. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630441/c-struct-with-zero-sized-array-members. The other is simply dyamically allocating memory for a vfariable sized array. You are mixing both as far as I can see. I suggest the latter in which case all that `csize + offset` etc is not needed

Comment: learn to user _strdup it makes life much simpler

Comment: @lurker my idea was to make the source code compile-able on both POSIX systems (just mac and linux really) and windows, but as you've pointed out I'm sure there are much better ways to deal with the differences in file paths

Comment: @pm100 wow I can't believe I hadn't heard of strdup() ;P, that'll definitely be of help! that link is very helpful, thank you again, I'll be sure to give it a good read

Comment: @GregorWattersHärtl it's a good goal. I was, though, pointing out that, in the WIN32 case, you code is comparing a pointer to a character, which is likely not what you want.

Comment: dirent.h doesnt exist on windows anyway

Comment: @lurker ah yes of course I see what you mean now! Since I'm writing the code on a mac my IDE didn't highlight the error... thanks again for pointing it out